# Why is Bootstrap's popover removing HTML element from the DOM?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to display a `div` inside a Bootstrap popover. In Meteor, I created a click event with the following:

Select the div:

```
var myDiv = $('.myDiv');
```

Initialize and show the popover:

```
$('#someButton').popover({html: true, content: myDiv});
$('#someButton').popover('show');
```

The problem is, whenever the event is triggered, somehow the original div gets removed from the DOM. It does show inside the popover though.
I have no clue why this is happening. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) on popover, the `content` property of the options takes a string or a function as the value but you are passing an element directly. Instead you can get the html of the div like this:

```
var myDiv = $('.myDiv').html();
```